# Parsing nested, "named" objects in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I am trying to parse JSON data returned in a Postman test for the first time but the complexity of my payload is causing parsing issues: how can I get to the "stage-guid" field in

```
{
    "Workflow": {
        "com.mycom.MyWorkflow": {
            "id": 10,
            "stages": [
                {
                    "com.mycom.MyStage": {
                        "id": 22,
                        "stage-guid": "00000000-0000-1111-1111-123456789012",
```

The following gets me to the Workflow object, but I have not figured out how to access inside the com.mycom.MyWorkflow object.

```
        var responseInJson = pm.response.json(); 
        var workFlowData = responseInJson.Workflow;
        console.log("in workflow", workFlowData);
```

I have tried workflowData.id, workflowData.object.id, workflowData.Object.id, workflowData[pm.variables.get("stage-guid")] but the test case never proceeds beyond these (incorrect) access attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to *walk down* the structure to get the value that you need. As there are objects and arrays to navigate, you would need to reference these correctly.

You also have *property* names with `dots` and `dashes` in them so you would need to use a mixture of dot and bracket notation to correctly reference those.

This should log that guide value in the console:

```js
let responseInJson = pm.response.json(),
    workFlowData = responseInJson.Workflow["com.mycom.MyWorkflow"].stages[0]["com.mycom.MyStage"]["stage-guid"];

console.log(workFlowData);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I definitely need to walk down the structure but am seeing the properties as "undefined"

Comment: I don't really know what the exact response is each time you make a request, you may have other things happening there which change the response in some way. Without more information about what you're seeing, it'll be tough to give you a solution for that.

Comment: Thanks.  Just needed more experimentation and a few JSON.stringify's